# .bat Find and Replace text

Tags: batch-file, windows-scripting

I have some files that contain some of if not all of the following:

Program RxBIN   RXPCN   RxGroup MemberID

not all files will have all of those headers but the ones that do I will need to replace so it looks like this:

@Program    @RxBIN  @RXPCN  @RxGroup    @MemberID

Thanks in Advance,
Joe

Comment: I don't quite understand what your objective is. Can you be a bit more specific?

Comment: Joe you asked the same on http://www.dostips.com/?t=Batch.FindAndReplace - and there seems to be a perfectly good solution posted there (it's not easy, I'd use gVim, vim, or a specific find/replace app).

Comment: I have exported from excel to delimited text (.txt)

First line of the .txt file I have all or some of the following within the first line:

Program RxBIN RXPCN RxGroup MemberID


what I need to do to is have them read as:

@Program @RxBIN @RXPCN @RxGroup @MemberID


I need to find from the first line "Program" and replace with "@Program" and so on. 

Thanks in advance,
Joe

Comment: @Rudi

I have followed that from the link you posted.
Within the terminal it echos back to me the correct replacement but doesn't write to file at all.

Comment: @Rudi I got that to work correctly but is there a way to have it search for all terms Program RxBIN RXPCN RxGroup MemberID and replace at once? Rather then one at a time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd still be inclined to go with a tool built for this purpose: [Batch Replacer](http://www.replsoft.com/replacer.html) seems to fit the bill perfectly.

But if you're dead set on it... something using the old [repl.bat](http://www.ousob.com/ng/edlin/ng96d9.php) with a multi arg parser... this becomes a bit of a monster that using the [DEBUG](http://mirror.href.com/thestarman/asm/debug/debug.htm) command but here's the final masterpiece:

**Source code:** *mmrepl.bat*

```
@ECHO OFF
setLocal EnableDelayedExpansion

::: mmrepl - Replaces one or more strings with others, in file(s)
:::
::: syntax: mmrepl.bat $file $find $replace [$find $replace] ...
:::            $file    [in] - file to be parsed
:::            $find    [in] - string to find
:::            $replace [in] - string to replace with
:::
:::         * $find & $replace should be supplied in pairs, n multiples allowed
:::         * $file can be a single file (eg.txt) or a file filter (*.txt)
:::           you can supply any command that works with 'dir /b $file'
:::           so paths and drives are also valid.
:::         * $find,$replace strings can be single words, or strings enclosed
:::            in quotes (which will be stripped)
if "%~1"=="" findstr "^:::" "%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
if not exist %1 echo No files matching %1 found&GOTO:EOF

::Creates the following log file:
set log=%0.log
::Temporarily creates the following files but cleans up
set replscr=TEMPDEBUG.SCR
set cmplsrc=TEMPEDLN.SCR

echo To see the work of %0.bat view the log file %log%
echo Multi-Multi Replacement (%0.bat)>%log%
echo.>>%log%
set "files=%1"
shift
set mmreplcmd=
:: Pair up find/replaces
:strippairs
set p1=%1
set p1=!p1:"=!
set p2=%2
set p2=!p2:"=!
SET mmreplcmd=%mmreplcmd%'1R%p1%' 1A '%p2%' 0D 0A 
echo Replacing "%p1%" with "%p2%" >> %log%
shift
shift
if "%~1" neq "" goto:strippairs

::Build script
echo N%cmplsrc% > %replscr%
echo E CS:100 %mmreplcmd%'E' 0D 0A>> %replscr%
echo RCX >> %replscr%
echo 40 >> %replscr%
echo W >> %replscr%
echo Q >> %replscr%
DEBUG < %replscr% > NUL
::Execute on files
for /f %%a IN ('dir /b %files%') do (
  echo.>>%log%
  echo *** File: %%a >> %log%
  EDLIN %%a < %cmplsrc% >> %log%
)
DEL %replscr%
DEL %cmplsrc%
```

**NOTE**: I had to remove the "is contained" within searching of *repl.bat* because you're adding an ampersand to each title so it's always containing... my testing shows this works fine, but YMMV (test).

Answer (score 1):

This can be done trivially with `sed` (the **s**tream **ed**itor) which is available for Windows in [several](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/sed.htm) [places](http://www.cornerstonemag.com/sed/).

It could be done with something like

```
sed -e "s/\(Program\|RxBIN\|RXPCN\|RxGroup\|MemberID\)/@\1/g" myfile.txt > newfile.txt
```

This is a regular expression that basically says "substitute for the word 'Program' or 'RxBIN' or 'RXPCN' or 'RxGroup' or 'MemberID', an at-sign and whatever word was matched."

There are a lot of great Unix commands which have been ported to Windows that can be extremely helpful.

Comment: Unix-originated tools are usually the best option in these cases, especially if you dont want to "roll-your-own" with Java or C#.